# How to hide Facebook Comments count if post has no comments yet

Tags: comments, facebook-comments

I have configured my web application to display Facebook comments and comment count in the post details template... It is displaying perfectly when there is a comment, but  I would like to hide the "x Comments" part when there is no comment posted.

```
< fb:comments-count href="[ARTICLELINK]"/>< /fb:comments-count> Comments
```

This is my template to display the comment count...

In my application's own comments feature, I could use the [hascomments][commentcount]Comments[/hascomments] template...

However, I couldn't find which token to use for Facebook comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The span is given the class 'fb_comments_count_zero' if there are no comments, so you can set that class to be display:none in your styleshet

Answer (score 1):

Put the above code you have into a `div` with an `id="hideMeIfZero"`. After Facebook has had time to parse the `fb:comments-count` tag, then use JavaScript to parse the `innerText` of the div "hideMeIfZero" for the count.

If the count is 0, then hide the `div` using CSS.